# Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundException on ArrayList of Class Objects

Tags: java, arraylist

Good day, I have a bit of design problem i can't really get my head through and i hope i can explain it clearly for all to understand. i have a ClassA which is a singleton that contains an Arraylist of a ClassB so ClassA is:

```
   private classA(){
    //private constructor
}

public static synchronized classA getClassA(){
    if(ClassA == null){         
        ClassA = new ClassA();
    }
    return ClassA;
}

private ArrayList<ClassB> classb = new ArrayList<ClassB>(5);

public ArrayList<ClassB> getClassB(){
    return this.classb;
}

public ClassB getLastClassB() {
    return this.classb.get(this.classb.size() - 1);
}
```

In ClassB, i have an ArrayList of ClassD of which ClassD is just a class of getters and setters, so my ClassB is:

```
    public ClassB() {

}

private ArrayList<ClassD> classd = new ArrayList<ClassD>();


    public ArrayList<ClassD> getClassD(){
        return this.ClassD;
    }

    public ClassD getLastClassD() {
        return this.ClassD.get(this.ClassD.size() - 1);
    }
```

so that when i want to the list in ClassA object with classB and classD objects, i do

```
 ClassA  A = ClassA.getClassA();


        Class B B = new ClassB();

         ClassD D = new ClassD();
           //do some setters here for D

           B.getClassD.add(D)

           // do some things in B

           A.getClassB.add(B)
```

but when i try to access this in another class, i get a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 which i guess is from the ClassB holding the ArrayList of ClassD because other functionalities are working..

```
  for(int i = 0; i < classA.getClassB.size(); i++)
   if(classA.getClassB().get(i).getClassD().size() > 0){ //java.lang.indexOutOfBoundsException
```

Any ideas what could be wrong or is my design implementation way off?.. i can't make the ClassB another Singleton because then i would have the same ClassB Object in the ArrayList ClassA. Any idea of a better implementation?.. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no item in ArrayList<classB> or ArrayList<classD> Please check

Comment: new ArrayList<ClassB>(5); creates empty list with initial capacity 5, not list with 5 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `this.ClassD.get(this.ClassD.size() - 1)` and another similar line of code, is `size()` call always guaranteed to return value greater than zero? In other words, can you guarantee that the list always has at least one element? Apparently not, so yes, it is a bad design.

Your `getLastClassX()` methods should be prepared to return `null` and therefore call `!isEmpty()` on the list before attempting getting the item at size()-1.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i need improve my english.

The problem should be the follow:
if getclassb return an array of B but one of them are not initializated then you do .getClassD then java throw the exception